# Why is the PowerShell script in Azure DevOps pipeline not updating the README.md file?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I am trying to create a PowerShell task in my Azure DevOps pipeline that will change the contents of a markdown file in the same repository. When I run the pipeline, everything passes with no error messages however, the markdown file remains unchanged.

The README.md file looks like:

```
App Name | Dev | QA | Prod
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
Project Name   |d0.0.0     | q0.0.0 | p0.0.0
```

My YAML pipeline file looks like:

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: "(Get-Content ./README.md) -Replace 'Project Name', 'New Project Name' | Set-Content './README.md'"
    
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

Am I missing a script or task that will update the README?

Comment: To change a file in Git repository you need commit and push changes. Your pipeline is changing only a file in cloned locally repository

Comment: @IvanIgnatiev So I tried running `- checkout: self persistCredentials: true` and got `Cannot find path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/README.md' because it does not exist.` which doesn't make sense because both files are in the same root directory